# How to set the content of a NSScrollview with an existing NSView in the storyboard XCode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, uiscrollview, storyboard

I have a NSViewController that contains a NSScrollView, I would like to add the content of that NSScrollView as a NSView defined in the Storyboard but I can't do it in any way.

I do not want to create the content programmatically, I would prefer to define it on the storyboard because the content is static.

```
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: NSScrollView!
scrollView.addSubview(//What to add here?)
```

This question is similar to this referred to iOS programming [How to use UIScrollView in Storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12905568/how-do-i-use-uiscrollview-in-storyboard).

Comment: What is the problem? I just tried dragging a scroll View into a NSViewController, and then an NSView into the ScrollView, and it all seemed to work fine on the storyboard.

Comment: @emrys57 the problem is that in the NSScrollView you can't "prepare" the entire view because of the fixed dimensions of a window, I would "prepare" it outside on a bigger view controller that I would add in the NSScrollView.

Comment: @emrys57 same question but about iOS, it has not a similar solution for OS X programming http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12905568/how-do-i-use-uiscrollview-in-storyboard

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27440433/how-to-embed-a-storyboard-view-controller-in-an-nsscrollview-os-x-10-10-to-mak see my answer there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27440433/how-to-embed-a-storyboard-view-controller-in-an-nsscrollview-os-x-10-10-to-mak/33745624#33745624

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to use a xib file.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when dealing with NSScrollViews, it always helps to use constraints (especially if your app is universal for different versions of iPhone/iPad). Have you tried working with them?